# Deform 2.0.4: Adding custom placeholder text to CheckedPasswordWidget

Tags: python, pyramid, deform

Is adding a custom placeholder text in `CheckedPasswordWidget()` supported by Deform? If yes, how can it be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Your question shows no research effort. One place to look for resolutions to issues is in the issue tracker or open pull requests of a project, like this one [Added html attributes support (e.g. including placeholder and maxlength)](https://github.com/Pylons/deform/pull/345). It has not been merged because it lacks tests and documentation, but it should work.